# Custom CSS with JBoss jDocBook maven plugin

Tags: css, maven, plugins, jboss, docbook

I'm trying to include custom CSS file into the HTML generated by jDocBook plugin.
Here is the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jdocbook-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDocumentName>book.xml</sourceDocumentName>
        <imageResource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/images</directory>
        </imageResource>
        <cssResource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/css</directory>
        </cssResource>
        <formats>
            <format>
                <formatName>pdf</formatName>
                <stylesheetResource>classpath:/docbook/fo/docbook.xsl</stylesheetResource>
            </format>
            <format>
                <formatName>html</formatName>
                <stylesheetResource>classpath:/docbook/html/chunk.xsl</stylesheetResource>
            </format>
        </formats>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have a file named `driver.css` in my `src/main/css`.
After build this file appears under `target/docbook/publish/en-US/html` alongside `book.html`, but it doesn't get included.

I also tried to add

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="driver.css" type="text/css"?>
```

to the `book.xml`, but that doesn't seem to help.

Am I missing any configuration parameters here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to style HTML output with custom CSS one has to pass `html.stylesheet=<path to css file>` to the XSLT processor. To do this using JDocBook plugin, one has to add following under `<configuration>`:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <options>
        <transformerParameters>
            <html.stylesheet>driver.css</html.stylesheet>
        </transformerParameters>
    </options>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Shame it's not described in [plugin documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/maven-jdocbook-plugin/)

And just to be clear, xml-stylesheet thing is irrelevant